# Socket re-write after failed

Tags: c, windows, linux, tcp

Here is the environment:

```
client -> router -> server
```

client will keep writing data to server even if the connection is broken.

Here is steps:

1. router has some problems, so client will get error message.
2. router are recovered

Can client write the data to the server as before.

PS: it's a TCP connection.

Comment: I don't think it can be done without hacking.  Even if it works, the server would probably deny any data sent after the connection shutdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[TCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) is designed to tolerate temporary failures. Buffering, sequencing, acknowledgements, timeouts and retransmission mechanisms built into TCP would take care of some *dropped* packets. The ends of the connected TCP stream would just see a delay while route recovers. Client might overflow its socket send buffer and return an error from the send call, and it's up to you how to handle that (waiting, retrying, bailing).

This would not work though if your router is really a [NAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) firewall, which consumer-grade "routers" usually are.

This would also not work if server software decides to close your connection after some period of perceived inactivity.

I suggest investing some time into understanding [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Suite) a bit more, maybe buying a [book](http://www.kohala.com/start/tcpipiv1.html) :)